# Continuous map and discrete topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification

Take $A$, $B$ two topological sets such that $B$ is equipped with the discrete topology. Let be $f:A \rightarrow B$ a continuous function. I was thinking about the following statement

> let over the set $B$ an arbitrary topology then $f$ is again a continuous function.

This seems trivial to me, because taken an open set of the new topology it is open for the discrete topology and so the inverse image is again an open set on $A$.

I would be glad to have a confirm or a counterexample of my reasoning, thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: In general, if $\tau\subseteq\tau'$ are two topologies on a set $B$ (we say $\tau'$ is *finer* than $\tau$, or $\tau$ is *coarser* than $\tau'$), then any map $f\colon A\to B$ that is continuous relative to $\tau'$ will also be continuous relative to $\tau$. The discrete topology is the *finest* topology you can put on $B$, so any map that is continuous relative to the discrete topology on $B$ will be continuous relative to any other topology on $B$.. The dual statement for topologies on $A$ holds, with the indiscrete topology being the coarsest.

Comment: The hypotheses imply that $f^{-1}\{b\}$ is open in $A$ for every $b\in B$ because $\{b\}$ is open in the discrete topology on $B$. So for any $C\subset B$ we have $f^{-1}C=\cup_{b\in C}f^{-1}\{b\}$ which is open in $A$ regardless of whether $C$ belongs to some topology on $B$ or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is completely correct. Having fewer open sets in the codomain and/or more open sets in the domain leaves a continuous function still continuous in the new topology.